# If we inject charge carriers into insulators, will they become conductors?

Tags: electricity, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Since there're also valance band and empty band in insulators, if we introduce electrons in empty band or holes in valance band, will it conduct electric current like semiconductors?

For example, we can expose insulators under ionizing radiation to induce electron-hole production.

Comment: Yes it will. It will take a lot of injection, which is harder because the gap is so much larger. But they will conduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common insulator behaves, in principle, like a semiconductor only with a larger bandgap. If, e.g. you supply enough photons with high enough energy to lift electrons from the valence band into the conduction band, you can get the insulator pretty much conductive.

Comment: So insulators are actually wide band gap semiconductors.

Comment: Yes, you could consider it like that, but very wide gap...

Comment: A good example is diamond...